# Has anyone using Firebase in their Android app experienced long loading times

Tags: android, firebase, performance, firebase-cloud-messaging

The Firebase BOM has over 100k methods and when I add it to my app Android Studio errors out saying it only supports 64k methods. Added multidex support to support the BOM but then loading the main activity takes 5 to 10 seconds. Really? I really wanted to use Firebase and now I'm forced to use other cloud providers for my apps. The most important thing for me was FCM but I can't use it. Why is the BOM so big? Seems terribly inefficient.

Comment: Android studio supports multi-dex projects for years so the 64k method limit (per dex file) is not a big deal.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. The app takes 5-10 seconds to load

Comment: What device do you use for testing? What FB libraries do you include? As far as I remember you don't have to include all firebase libraries, juts can pick just the one you need.